# Where Visual Studio 11 beta Web installer download installation data?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Where Visual Studio 11 beta Web installer download installation data?

I want to move installation data to other computer, and there install Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you might be able to find it, moving it is likely to be unreliable – any issues you find (it is a *beta*) might be down to hacking the installer rather than faults in the beta.

If you want to download once for multiple installs then download the installer. The web installer optimises the current install at the cost of every install having to download.